# Implementing multi-tenancy for a mature enterprise application

Tags: java, architecture, glassfish, multi-tenant

I've been tasked with making an enterprise application multi-tenant. It has a Java/Glassfish BLL using SOAP web services and a PostgreSQL backend. Each tenant has its own database, so (in my case at least) "multi-tenant" means supporting multiple databases per application server.

The current single-tenant appserver initializes a C3P0 connection pool with a connection string that it gets from a config file. My thinking is that now there will need to be one connection pool per client/database serviced by the appserver.

Once a user is logged in, I can map it to the right connection pool by looking up its tenant. My main issue is how to get this far - when a user is first logged in, the backend's `User` table is queried and the corresponding `User` object is served up. It seems I will need to know which database to use with only a username to work with.

My only decent idea is that there will need to be a "config" database - a centralized database for managing tenant information such as connection strings. The BLL can query this database for enough information to initialize the necessary connection pools. But since I only have a username to work with, it seems I would need a centralized username lookup as well, in other words a `UserName` table with a foreign key to the `Tenant` table.

This is where my design plan starts to smell, giving me doubts. Now I would have user information in two separate databases, which would need to be maintained synchronously (user additions, updates, and deletions). Additionally, usernames would now have to be globally unique, whereas before they only needed to be unique per tenant.

I strongly suspect I'm reinventing the wheel, or that there is at least a better architecture possible. I have never done this kind of thing before, nor has anyone on my team, hence our ignorance. Unfortunately the application makes little use of existing technologies (the ORM was home-rolled for example), so our path may be a hard one.

I'm asking for the following:

- Criticism of my existing design plan, and suggestions for improving or reworking the architecture.
- Recommendations of existing technologies that provide a solution to this issue. I'm hoping for something that can be easily plugged in late in the game, though this may be unrealistic. I've read about [jspirit](http://jspirit.sourceforge.net/), but have found little information on it - any feedback on it or other frameworks will be helpful.

**UPDATE:** The solution has been successfully implemented and deployed, and has passed initial testing. Thanks to [@mikera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214010/mikera) for his helpful and reassuring answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some quick thoughts:

- You will definitely need **some form of shared user management index** (otherwise you can't associate a client login with the right target database instance). However I would suggest making this very lightweight, and only using it for initial login. Your User object can still be pulled from the client-specific database once you have determined which database this is.
- You can **make the primary key [clientID, username]** so that usernames don't need to be unique across clients.
- Apart from this thin user index layer, I would **keep the majority of the user information where it is in the client-specific databases**. Refactoring this right now will probably be too disruptive, you should get the basic multi-tenant capability working first.
- You will need to **keep the shared index in sync** with the individual client databases. But I don't think that should be too difficult. You can also "test" the synchronisation and correct any errors with an batch job, which can be run overnight or by your DBA on demand if anything ever gets out of sync. I'd treat the client databases as the master, and use this to rebuild the shared user index on demand.
- **Over time you can refactor** towards a fully shared user management layer (and even in the end fully shared client databases if you like. But save this for a future iteration.....

Comment: +1 This answer is reassuring. The config database will be very light - as you say, only used during the connection pool init and username lookup.  Excellent point about a nightly batch job to clean up/report loose ends.